# How to generate data from Space-Track website using api

Tags: python, csv

I want to fetch data from the website https://www.space-track.org/documentation#/api
the above website offers multiple API's to generate data using specific API's like SATCAT and TLE, I am unsure how I can do that, can someone help me on this to generate data using those 2 API's.

Many Thanks in advance

I don't have much knowledge in using API's

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have credentials  to authenticate the API requests:

1. Choose an HTTP client library like requests in python
2. Make an API request:

   > SATCAT API: The SATCAT API allows you to retrieve information about satellite catalog data. To fetch SATCAT data, construct an API request URL with the desired parameters and send an HTTP GET request to the API endpoint. For example, to fetch the details of a specific satellite identified by its International Designator (INTDES), you can make a request like:

   ```
   requests.get(https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/satcat/INTDES/{satellite_intdes}/orderby/SATNAME/format/json)
   ```

   Replace {satellite_intdes} with the actual International Designator of the satellite you want to fetch.

   > TLE API: The TLE (Two-Line Elements) API allows you to retrieve satellite orbit data in TLE format. To fetch TLE data, construct an API request URL with the desired parameters and make an HTTP GET request to the API endpoint. For example, to fetch the latest TLE data for a specific satellite identified by its NORAD Catalog Number, you can make a request like:

   ```
   requests.get(https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/tle_latest/NORAD_CAT_ID/{norad_cat_id}/orderby/EPOCH desc/limit/1/format/tle)
   ```

   Replace {norad_cat_id} with the actual NORAD Catalog Number of the satellite you want to fetch.
3. Handle the API response: Once you receive the API response, you can parse and process the data based on the format provided (e.g., JSON or TLE). You can extract the required information from the response and use it in your invoicing application as needed.

Here's an example of how you can fetch data from the Space-Track API using Python and the requests library

```
import requests

# API credentials
username = "your_username"
password = "your_password"

# Base URL for Space-Track API
base_url = "https://www.space-track.org"

# SATCAT API endpoint
satcat_endpoint = "/basicspacedata/query/class/satcat/INTDES/{satellite_intdes}/orderby/SATNAME/format/json"

# TLE API endpoint
tle_endpoint = "/basicspacedata/query/class/tle_latest/NORAD_CAT_ID/{norad_cat_id}/orderby/EPOCH desc/limit/1/format/tle"

# Function to fetch SATCAT data
def fetch_satcat_data(satellite_intdes):
    # Construct the API request URL
    url = base_url + satcat_endpoint.replace("{satellite_intdes}", satellite_intdes)

    # Send GET request with authentication
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        # Process the data as needed
        return data
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch SATCAT data. Status code:", response.status_code)
        return None

# Function to fetch TLE data
def fetch_tle_data(norad_cat_id):
    # Construct the API request URL
    url = base_url + tle_endpoint.replace("{norad_cat_id}", norad_cat_id)

    # Send GET request with authentication
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.text
        # Process the data as needed
        return data
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch TLE data. Status code:", response.status_code)
        return None

# Example usage
satellite_intdes = "ISS"
satcat_data = fetch_satcat_data(satellite_intdes)
if satcat_data:
    print("SATCAT data for", satellite_intdes, ":", satcat_data)

norad_cat_id = "25544"
tle_data = fetch_tle_data(norad_cat_id)
if tle_data:
    print("TLE data for NORAD ID", norad_cat_id, ":", tle_data)
```

Here is a full guide to this topic: https://nbntechstreet.com/2023/06/13/fetching-space-data-with-python-a-guide-to-using-the-space-track-api/